# C - Loading a Struct Containing a Pointer to a Pointer

Tags: c, string

This produces an incompatibility warning:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int key;
  int data;
  struct htData_* next;
  struct htData_* prev;
}htData_;

typedef struct
{
  int num_entries;
  struct htData_** entries;
}ht_;

ht_* new_ht(int num_entries);
int ht_add(ht_* ht_p, int key, int data);

int main()
{
  int num_entries = 20;
  //crate a hash table and corresponding reference                                                                                                              
  ht_* ht_p = new_ht(num_entries);
  //add data to the hash table                                                                                                                                  
  int key = 1305;
  ht_add(ht_p,key%num_entries,20);

  return 0;
}

ht_* new_ht(int num_entries)
{
  ht_ *ht_p;
  ht_ ht;
  ht.num_entries = num_entries;
  ht_p = &ht;

  //create an array of htData                                                                                                                                   
  htData_ *htDataArray;
  htDataArray = (htData_*) malloc(num_entries * sizeof(htData_));
  //point to the pointer that points to the first element in the array                                                                                          
  ht.entries = &htDataArray; // WARNING HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  return ht_p;
}
```

I'm trying to copy the `**ptr` to the `struct` containing a `**ptr`.

**Update:** My simplified code was not accurate so I've posted the actual code.

Comment: Also mention that which line is producing warning

Comment: what is `htData_ array[20] = htDataArray;` intended to do?

Comment: I've added a better and easier to understand test failure case replacing specifically that line. Thanks for looking and I apologize for the lack of organization...

Comment: You only need to make the cast on malloc if you are in C++. In plain C it is usually recomended to skip the cast (it is verbose and more error prone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `struct htData_` and `htData_` are *not* the same thing!  As far as the compiler is concerned, `struct htData_` doesn't exist—it's an incomplete type.  `htData_`, on the other hand, is a `typedef` for an anonymous structure.  For a more detailed analysis, see [Difference between `struct` and `typedef struct` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612350#612350).

So, you're getting a warning because `ht.entries` is declared as the type `struct htData_**`, but the right-hand side of that assignment has type `<anonymous struct>**`.  To fix this, you need to define `struct htData_`:

```
typedef struct htData_
{
    ...
} htData_;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is not proper:

```
htData_ array[20] = htDataArray;
```

You cannot assign a pointer to an array.

In your edited code, here is the problematic line:

```
//point to the pointer that points to the first element in the array                                                                                          
  ht.entries = &htDataArray;
```

Actually, syntactically it's correct, so it should not give warning. But you are doing wrong stuff here. If you want `ht.entries` pointing to the first element of array than you need to declare it as,

```
htData_* entries;  // 'struct' keyword not needed ahead of declaration
```

and assign it as,

```
ht.entries = &htDataArray[0];
```

Comment: How about with the updated replacement of that line? I still get the error yet it makes sense to assign a ** to a ** of the same type.

Comment: The warning is still produced if ht.entries = &htDataArray; is replaced by ht.entries = &htDataArray[0];. Did I misunderstand your comment? Also, I'm not trying to just have ht.entries point to the first element in the array. I want a pointer that points to a pointer pointing to the first element in the array. More simply, htDataArray points to element 0 in the array. I want to point to htDataArray, which is a **.

Comment: @nick_name, did you change the declaration to `htData_* entries;` ?

Comment: I could do that, but that wouldn't accomplish what I'm going for. I want a pointer to a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: But current code will not help you getting the pointer to the first element too. First element of the array is of type `htData_` and pointer to that will be `htData_*`. So you have to change the declaration of `entries`.